# $c=zw+z$ , solve for $w$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$c=zw+z$, solve for $w$.

I know this sounds basic but i want to be sure. This is a site homework, My result was $w={c\over z}-1$ but the site says the correct answer is $w={(c-z)\over z}$.
anything possibly wrong with my solution ?
thanks!

Comment: No, nothing is wrong with your solution.  Check your algebra.

Comment: $(c/z)-1$ and $(c-z)/z$ are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you do the algebra:

$$c=zw+z\to c-z=zw\to \frac{c-z}{z}=w$$

or

$$c=zw+z\to c=z(w+1)\to \frac{c}{z}=w+1\to \frac{c}{z}-1=w$$

So

$$\frac{c-z}{z}=\frac{c}{z}-1$$

Comment: thanks for taking the time!